# NumberPicker does not work with keyboard input value in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a numberpicker control in android activity. It works good when clicking those "+" and "-" buttons. But when I enter a number from keyboard it and try to get the current entered value in program, it does not give value which was entered by keyboard. I am working with C# Xamarin android.

is there any key press event or something which can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create set a Custom OnEditorActionListener on the EditText of the NumberPicker:

```
NumberPicker picker;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.test);
            picker  = FindViewById<NumberPicker>(Resource.Id.numberPicker);
            picker.MaxValue = 40;
            picker.MinValue = 1;
            EditText editText= (EditText)picker.GetChildAt(1);
            editText.SetOnEditorActionListener(new CustomActionListener());

        }

 public class CustomActionListener : Java.Lang.Object,EditText.IOnEditorActionListener
        {

            public bool OnEditorAction(TextView v, Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction actionId, KeyEvent e)
            {

                if(actionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done)
                {
                    // Here is you number
                    string countNumber = v.Text;
                }
                return true;

            }

            public IntPtr Handle
            {
                get { return base.Handle; }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                base.Dispose();
            }
        }
```